# ioredis - I can't filter data

Tags: javascript, redis, ioredis

First, I created a form. Every time users type an entry, it shouldn't be overwritten. so it needs to be added as an extra, I found the `append` command in redis and applied it. But now I don't know how to filter and fetch the data.

Append command, here I am making the data JSON

```
const newEntry = {
      owner_id,
      message,
      created_at: Date.now(),
      score: 1,
      ip: 'NA',
    }
await redis.append('features', JSON.stringify(newEntry))
```

JSON example, I need to filter with owner_id:

```
{"owner_id":30902468,"message":"test","created_at":1643755923014,"score":1,"ip":"NA"}
```

[Redis docs here](https://redis.io/documentation)

[ioredis](https://github.com/luin/ioredis)

Answer (score 0):

The `APPEND` works on strings, it's not exactly what you are looking for...

You can use lists and create a list for each user:

```js
const newEntry = {
  owner_id,
  message,
  created_at: Date.now(),
  score: 1,
  ip: 'NA'
};

await redis.rpush(`features:${owner_id}`, JSON.stringify(newEntry));

await redis.lrange(`features:${owner_id}`, 0, -1);
```

In case you need to run more complicated queries, you should consider [RediSearch](https://oss.redis.com/redisearch/) + [RedisJSON](https://oss.redis.com/redisjson/)